# Showing the following properties

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Showing the following properties without using Venn diagrams(it's pretty obvious with using it, but I want to find a solution using mathematical logic)

Show that $ A \subseteq B $ is equivalent with:

(1) $A \cup B=B $

(2) $A \cap B =A$

(3) $A\setminus B = \emptyset $

I've started to prove the properties above with writing the definitions of the operations:

$ A \subseteq B = (\forall x)(x \in A \implies x \in B)$

$A \cup B={ \{x:x \in A \lor x \in B \} } $

$ A \cap B={ \{x:x \in A \land x \in B \} } $

$A\setminus B ={ \{x: x \in A \land x\notin B \} }$

Should I write now to check the elements in a truth table or how can I continue the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that two sets $P$ and $Q$ are equal, show that every element in $P$ is in $Q$, and vice versa.

So, for example, for the first one:

Take any element $x$ from $A \cup B$. Then $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. But since $A \subseteq B$, if $x \in A$, then $x \in B$. So definitely $x \in B$.

So now you know that $A \cup B \subseteq B$. Now go the other way around and show that any element $x$ in $B$ is in $A \cup B$.